# How to get price instead of data-price/value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, magento

What the title says... How can I grab price="".

In my HTML below, this is in Magento, which I'm trying to override by defining a custom Javascript. That's why I did not post it to Magento Stack Overflow. The option inside select tag is like this:

```
<option id="sample" value="46" price="2">50 x 46cm +$2.00</option>
```

How can I grab the price?

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var a = $(this).data(price);
  alert( a );
});
```

Comment: using price as attribute is not the right way use data-price="2" instead of price

Comment: You are not reading faizanbeg.....In my question I told everyone that this is in magento form and I need only to override the js to make it work. By default magento uses price instead of data-price.

Answer (score 2):

You need the attribute from the selected child

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
      var a = $(this).find(':selected').attr('price');
      alert( a );
});
```

Assumes that the `<select>` is not set as `multiple`. Also more common to use html5 `data-` attributes but should work fine as is

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
     var selected = $( "select option:selected " ).attr('price');
     console.log(selected);
});
```

OR if you have

```
$('.sample_list').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $( ".sample_list option:selected " ).attr('price');
    console.log(selected);
});
```